# Error: [ngRepeat:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_item_ in _collection_[ track by _id_]' but got '(name,surname)in controller.students'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi I am trying to iterate json object with ng-repeat, when I Iterated array it worked fine, but with json object it is failing.

Here is my javascript code:

```
 var appModule = angular.module('appModule',[]);
 appModule.controller('appController',[function(){
    this.students = {
        "abc":"abc",
        "xyz":"xyz",
        "xyz":"xyz"
    }
}]);
```

And here is my html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appModule">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController as controller">
<div ng-repeat="(firstName,lastName)in controller.students">
<span>Name:{{firstName}} Surname: {{lastName}}</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try to show data this way

```
<body ng-controller="appController as controller">
  <div ng-repeat="student in controller.students">
    <span>Name:{{student.firstName}} Surname: {{student.lastName}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/28037977)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<body ng-controller="appController as controller">
<div ng-repeat="(firstName,lastName) in  controller.students">
<span>Name:{{firstName}} Surname: {{lastName}}</span>
</div>
```

you are just missing a whitespace :)

Answer (score -1):

There should be space between (firstName,lastName) and in,

```
 <body ng-controller="appController as controller">
  <div ng-repeat="(firstName, lastName) in controller.students">
    <span>Name:{{firstName}} Surname: {{lastName}}</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/vaXCMXhuc5VIk0MWT70X?p=preview)**

Comment: Is it really the solution? Still getting the same error.